# A quick way to test on browser console if AngularJS is running on the page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

You can test that jquery is running on the page by simply typing this in the browser console:

`$`

and that returns

`function()`

Is there something similar you can do with AngularJS?

Comment: there is a variable called `angular` in the global namespace. If you want more details take a look into [public](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/AngularPublic.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just doing:

```
angular
```

If you would like information about the version, you can then look at `angular.version`

Comment: If angular is undefined trying to call `angular.version` will throw an error. Can you not just check `angular`?